# How to display recall and precision in TFLearn?

Tags: tflearn

I'm quiet new with tflearn. I did a cnn classifier, which classifies in 17 different classes. I run the code without any problem, and it shows me the accuracy and the loss. I was wondering how can I display the recall and precision for each class. My code is based in the example of CNN classifier to IMDB dataset of TFLearn.
Thank you for your work and your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this is to use SKLearn's metrics library. An example from some [LSTM implementation on Github](https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/LSTM-Human-Activity-Recognition#and-finally-the-multi-class-confusion-matrix-and-metrics):

```
print "Precision: {}%".format(100*metrics.precision_score(y_test, predictions, average="weighted"))
print "Recall: {}%".format(100*metrics.recall_score(y_test, predictions, average="weighted"))
print "f1_score: {}%".format(100*metrics.f1_score(y_test, predictions, average="weighted"))
```

Here, `y_test` is the Y values of your test data.

`predictions` is the output of your `model.predict(X_test)` where `X_test` are the X values of your test data.

Another one to look at is [metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html).